# Fluid modal height

Tags: html, css

Been trying to get a fluid height modal working and have run into a bit of a snag. My parent object is 70% height and am trying to have content height span the full 100% of it's parent but keep having overflow issues. Below is the code and jsfiddle any help is appreciated :)

http://jsfiddle.net/NS7UP/

CSS

```
html {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 70%;
    background: #b10000;
    display: block;
    .modalWrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        .modalHeader {
            width: 100%;
            height: 45px;
            background: blue;
            display: block;
        }
        .modalSubheader {
            width: 100%;
            height: 25px;
            background: #007755;
            display: block;
        }
        .modalBody {
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        .modalFooter {
            height: 45px;
            width: 100%;
            background: cyan;
            bottom: 0;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modalWrapper">
    <div class="modalHeader">Turkey</div>
    <div class="modalSubheader">Chicken</div>
    <div class="modalBody">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class="modalFooter"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
padding-bottom: /*Required %*/;
```

for adjustable, responsive height properties.